# Troubleshooting 1935 error during VC++ redist installs

Tags: windows-8.1, visual-c++, redistributable

I have been trying to install earlier VC++ redists on Windows 8.1 64-bit for a couple of days now and consistently get *error 1935*. Finally I found this:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2005/11/10/491653.aspx

Instead of seeing an MSI value in v2.0.50727 as he describes, I see a whole bunch of 4-digit keys *inside* v2.0.50727 each with their own MSI value. Is it safe to delete all of them? Should I just delete the v2.0.50727 altogether?

Here is a screenshot of the error:

[image: Error Message]

Comment: try this: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/970652

Comment: You are not attempting to install the .NET Framework, so I don't think the linked blog post applies to your situation.  It was not meant to be a general post to solve all 1935 errors.  It was specific to errors when installing Visual Studio 2005.

Comment: What version of VC Redist are you attempting to install?  Can you post the exact error message you're getting?

Comment: Also, here is a [good guide](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2004/11/10/255346.aspx) to debugging 1935 errors in MSIs.

Comment: @magicandre1981 the link in the article is potholed. I think it's supposed to point to the windows update troubleshooter, which I ran with no success

Comment: @heavyd 2005 - heres a screengrab http://ctrlv.in/627032

Answer (score 0):

FYI - only thing that helped was  a rollback using a disk image backup. The tool that microsoft supplied was useless.